# Hotels in Las Vegas near Caesar's Palace that accept 18 year olds

Tags: hotels, las-vegas

I plan on staying in Las Vegas for a conference in August. I'm planning this early because there are going to be some problems when it comes to age restrictions and I want to make sure everything is ready when the time comes.

I'm 16 years old at this time but will be 17 by August. My friend is 17 at this time, and he will be 18 by August. I was wondering what hotel is closest to Caesar's Palace in Las Vegas that allows reservations and check-in to be done by an 18 year-old. Unfortunately, it seems like Caesar's Palace has a minimum age of 21.

Comment: Although I don't know certain laws that pertain to Vegas, I do know that a lot of hotels won't care too much if you're under 18. I did a bit of traveling before I was 18 and was fine in hotels under my own name. Act professional and courteous and you will be fine.

Comment: I'm addition: hotels usually ask for a credit card. Most credit cards unless paired with a parent are only with those who are 18+. Debit cards can work but there will be a hold on some of your money.

Comment: @user79930 uhhh thats a pretty big risk to take. I have a debit card and so does my friend, but I'm pretty sure every hotel checks ID.

Comment: I have not had my ID checked once. Partly because I would dress nicer for my age. Just leaving some of my personal experience.

Comment: @user79930 Are you speaking in general or specifically about Las Vegas?  The thing is this town is pretty strict on age matters.

Comment: That question should be answered in my first comment. "I don't know certain laws that pertain to Vegas," so, I would have to be speaking in general.

Comment: If it’s for a conference, is it for work? If it’s for work, can the room be booked via a corporate travel agent or something like OnPeak? I’ve noticed a lot of age restrictions seem to go out the window if a corporation is on the hook for the bill. (I had this with renting cars before I turned 25 - I couldn’t rent one personally at a lot of places, but if my employer was booking it, the age on my drivers license suddenly didn’t matter.)

Comment: @bogardpd I am going to a conference but as an independent with my friend, not with a company.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will find it difficult to reserve a hotel room in Las Vegas if you are 18–21, and it is next to impossible to reserve a room in your own name if you are under 18 anywhere in the U.S.

[Vegas.com](https://www.vegas.com/), the site operated by the tourism bureau, is not comprehensive, but includes minimum age requirements and seems to be reasonably reliable. The only hotel it lists on the Strip renting to 18+ is the Travelodge Center Strip, and the only off-Strip hotel is the Westgate, which is a distance away near the Convention Center. The [policies page](http://www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/nevada/hilton-grand-vacations-on-the-las-vegas-strip-LASVSGV/about/policies.html) for Hilton Grand Vacations suggests that they are another option. Note that policies are always subject to change, so these properties may no longer be options come August, whereas others might be.

You may have additional options if you are willing to stay downtown or in other parts of the city, although public transportation is costly (the [SDX bus](https://www.rtcsnv.com/wp-content/uploads/routes/deuce-sdx.pdf) is $6 for a single ride or $8 for a daily pass).

The only other listing of hotels I was able to find was at [booking site LasVegasHotel.com](http://lasvegashotel.com/vegas/vegas-hotels-17.htm), but this list is not reliable, as it lists examples which the official site states are 21+ (e.g. Skylofts at MGM Grand) and moreover lists the Riviera, which was demolished almost three years ago.

There are alternatives to hotels, of course. Las Vegas has several hostels, and you could also attempt to make a reservation on a service like AirBnB, where the minimum age is 18.

Wherever you choose to stay, and regardless of where you make your reservation, I would call in advance and confirm that they will in fact accept reservations from people under 21. When you check in, the staff will ask for identification, and you do not want to be caught out if they accepted the online reservation in error.

Answer (score 6):

The [Westin Las Vegas](http://www.westinvegas.com/) is a half mile east down Flamingo Road from the strip, just behind the Flamingo Hotel.  Thier [hotel policy](http://www.westinvegas.com/hotel-policies) page on their website explicitly states:

> Age Requirement Policy
>   Guests must be 18 years or older with photo identification to reserve a guest room. Guests younger 18 must be accompanied by an adult. A valid, government-issued ID is required as proof of age.

In general, I have found any hotel which also operates a casino on their property requires a minimum check-in age of 21 years.  Given the large hotel casino resorts bordering Ceasar's Palace, I believe the Westin is the closest hotel which meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this as well, unfortunately I can only mark one answer as accepted. One thing I'm shocked to see is that this place costs more per night than Caesars Palace.

Comment: It's not so surprising when you consider virtually all mega hotel casino resorts earn most of their income through the casino side rather than the hotel/spa side.  The Best Western McCarran Inn also has a minimum check-in age of 18 and is showing only $85 a night.  It's only 3.5 miles away and should have no problem finding a quick uber given the proximity to the airport.  Since you didn't mention affordability in your question, it wasn't taken in to consideration.  Feel free to update your requirements for more detailed answers!

Comment: Yeah I guess, I don't know much about hotels but the Westin isn't that impressive... kind of a 3 star hotel to be honest, wish I could stay at the Palace. Not sure why you have to be 21 to just stay at the hotel, yes, you can't do casino or alcohol, but not sure why you would limit the amount of money you can make to age.

Comment: @BillRichard Because they're not making money on the hotel rooms, or some stuff like the buffet. They are a loss leader for the gaming operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely anecdotal, and outdated (over a decade ago), but here goes.

When I was 17, my friends and I took a road trip to Vegas. I had a debit card (Visa) which we thought would be enough, but we kept getting ID checked and turned away. We made our way down the strip and started getting to the seedier places. Finally, we just asked each place we went to, "do you check IDs?". Finally, the Algiers Hotel front desk man said no, and we were able to enjoy a very disappointing weekend in Las Vegas.